# Decomposition of a rectangular matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I am looking to decompose a rectangular matrix $X$ into the product of an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $S$ i.e. X=$US$. Any possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps only in for a particular type of matrix $X$, since $X=US$ requires
$$
X^T X = (US)^T US = S^TU^TUS = S^T S
$$
which is diagonal.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? You're saying it can only be found if X is what exactly?

Comment: the rows of $X$ must be a pairwise orthogonal set of vectors

Comment: What if that's the case?

Comment: if so then $X^TX$ gives you $S^2$ and hence $S$. if no diagonal entry is zero use $U=XS^{-1}$

Comment: Got it! Thanks!